# find an irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois extension with $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to $A_5$, which is the group consisting of all even permutations of 5 objects. Show there is an irreducible polynomials $g(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 20 such that $g(x)$ has a root in $K.$

My attempt:
By Cauchy's theorem, there is a subgroup of order 3 in $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})$. And  by Galois theory, there is a subgroup $E$ of $K$ such that $[K:E]=3$, and hence $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=20.$ Since $E$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree 20, there exists an element $\alpha\in E$ such that $deg(irr(\alpha,\mathbb{Q}))=20.$ Then $irr(\alpha,\mathbb{Q})=g(x)$ is the polynomial we want.

Does this argument make sense? (I'm actually not very sure how to justify the existence of the element $\alpha$ rigorously.) Please let me know if there're any mistakes in here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the argument is correct. The existence of $\alpha$ is a consequence of [Artin's primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Hope that helps!

Comment: You beat me to the answer by just a matter of seconds...

Comment: Hi @Alex, sorry! I've had that happen to me before. I think there should be some form of notification that someone else is writing an answer to a question if you are in the process of doing so. (I'm not sure if this was discussed on meta at any stage.) Of course, if there could be many good, alternate answers to one question, this could be problematic, so I'm not sure how one would implement such a system appropriately. (But with questions like this, where almost a one sentence answer suffices and there aren't really that many alternatives for answers, it might be useful.) Happy new year!

Comment: I guess I should've just posted the one sentence: I was spending time to explain why the primitive element theorem applies, etc.  But whatever, it's all good.  God bless you.